# What do you call a graph of value vs rank of the value?

Tags: sequences-and-series, graphing-functions, visualization

What do you call a graph of value vs rank of the value?

For example, say I make a census of the 2010 net income for a bunch of people.

- The graph of net income vs age gives me a: scatterplot
- The graph of net income vs location (latitude, longitude) gives me a: height map
- After sorting the net income values so the value in rank 1 is highest income, rank 2 is the next-highest, etc., then the graph of net income vs rank gives me a: ???

(This may be a question more about [information graphics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_graphics) than about math -- is there some other site, perhaps [Graphic Design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/), that is a better place for this kind of question than Math.StackExchange?)

My understanding is that [Zipf's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zipf%27s_law) often applies to such graphs.
Ideally I'd like a name for all such graphs, whether or not Zipf's law applies to them.
What do you call such a graph of value vs rank of the value?

Comment: You could maybe try [stats.SE](http://stats.stackexchange.com) if you don't get a good answer here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen them called simply "rank plots" or "rank–value plots" (or e.g. "rank–income plots", if income is what you're measuring).  Apparently, the term ["Zipf plot"](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22zipf+plot%22) is also sometimes used.